# Can not acces array value in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, post, associative-array

Have an php array made from POST data
    `$this->log->write(print_r($array , true));`

```
Array
(
[accept] => */*
[accept-encoding] => gzip, deflate
[signature] =>    37df88b6f845c21b1cda84cf3d3b94b0b15759b74f7387ceb0e9c8a6247c211f
[connection] => keep-alive
[content-length] => 610
[user-agent] => python-requests/2.10.0
)

$this->log->write(var_export($array , true).'var_export');

 array (
'accept' . "\0" . '' => '*/*',
'accept-encoding' . "\0" . '' => 'gzip, deflate',
'signature' . "\0" . '' => '37df88b6f845c21b1cda84cf3d3b94b0b15759b74f7387ceb0e9c8a6247c211f',
'connection' . "\0" . '' => 'keep-alive',
'content-length' . "\0" . '' => '610',
'user-agent' . "\0" . '' => 'python-requests/2.10.0',
)var_export
```

The problem I can not access array value with `$array['signature'];` it is empty.

Sorry question looks nub but it is not. Work with arrays before and no problem. Have tried this as well `$array["signature"];` `$array->signature;` empty returned.
Please help

Comment: plz put a `var_export($array)` in your question, to let us see exactly what is you var content, or a `var_dump($array)` as well. It also looks you are using a Framework, which one is it ?

Comment: Please provide, exact code where your are populating `$array` variable.

Comment: question updated with var_export

Comment: The `"\0"` is probably throwing off your array. Try `$array['signature'."\0"]`

Comment: Thank you @aynber `$array['signature'."\0"]` do the job. But what is ."\0"?

Comment: It's a null byte. If you don't need it, don't add it when you build your array.

Comment: Do you use a framework or something ? How do you get this array ?

Comment: @S.M.Nat found out why I guess .. https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP/issues/248

Comment: @S.M. Nat, if you are using sanitizing of keys then please check my updated solution. You might find it more compact. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, your keys are append somehow with `\0` (which is end string character in **C** if my memory is good)

Thats why when you try to gather key `signature` there is nothing, because the key is `signature\0`

So, you have two solutions, first is calling `$array['signature' . "\0"]` second is doing an array key sanitizing.

Like this :

```
$keys = array_map(function($key){ return trim($key); }, array_keys($array));
$array = array_combine($keys, array_values($array));
```

- Step 1: trim all keys
- Step 2: re-associating sanitized keys to values

**EDIT**

Found out why ... at least if you are using PHP7

In fact if you return an array from a function, this will add null bytes at the end of each array key. See github issue https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP/issues/248
Btw I guess your PHP7 version is old :p keep in mind to update it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can access it as:

```
$array["signature\0"];
```

`"\0"` is called `"NULL character"`, even though it will not be visible in outputting the array but it makes difference while accessing the index.

That's why "signature" and "signature\0" are not same even if they both will output 'signature' as later one has 10 characters while former has only 9 which makes it different while using it as an index.

If you are familiar with C then you can take reference from there that `"\0"` is used to end a string otherwise variable is consider as array of character instead of string.

As given in another answer, sanitization of keys can be another alternative. But i would rather use foreach to do so:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){unset($array[$key]);$array[trim($key)] = $val;}
echo $array['signature'];
```

It won't need two steps for sanitizing and assigning. It works in one.

*I hope it helps*